# How do I transferred text from <Entry/> and display this text from one page to another using Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have two pages:

```
WeatherPage.xaml
Favorites.xaml
```

I also have a button "Favorite" in `WeatherPage.xaml` page.

I want when the user writes something in `WeatherPage.xaml` in `<Entry/>` field and after pressing the button "Favorite" this text should be displayed on the other page `Favorites.xaml`.

Is there an option to keep the transferred text on the page `Favorites.xaml` to stay there even when the app is closed ?

I don't have a database and I'm looking for an example of how I can move text from one page to another and save it.

My code in `WeatherPage.xaml` is:

```
<Entry x:Name="_cityEntry"
                   Grid.Row="1" 
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Margin="5,0"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   BackgroundColor="Black"
                   TextColor="White"
                   Opacity="0.7"
                   Text="Moscow" />

            <ImageButton Source="blackheart.png"
                    Grid.Row="1" 
                    Grid.Column="3"
                    WidthRequest="40"
                    HeightRequest="40"
                    Opacity="0.7"
                    Clicked="OnGetFavorites"/>
```

In my `WeatherPage.xaml.cs` I insert this line of code on the button method:

```
void OnGetFavorites(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Preferences.Set("cityName", _cityEntry.Text);
    }
```

My `FavoritePage.xaml.cs` looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace WeatherLocationInfo.Views
{
    public partial class Favorites : ContentPage
    {
        public Favorites()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

            FavoriteCities();
        }

        private void FavoriteCities()
        {
            string cityName = Preferences.Get("cityName", "default_value");

            FavoriteCity.Text = cityName.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

When the application starts on the page, the first entered city is printed from `WeatherPage` to `Favorites` page, but when it changes the city and clicked the button again the content of the search bar is not updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to store data even when the app is closed without a database is to store the "_cityEntry text" as application preference. You can directly use the [Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android).

create a new preference key-value pair in `WeatherPage.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class WeatherPage : ContentPage
{
    public WeatherPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnGetFavorites(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Preferences.Set("cityName", _cityEntry.Text);
        Navigation.PushAsync(new FavoritePage());
    }
}
```

get the value of key `cityName` in `Favorites.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class FavoritePage : ContentPage
{
    public FavoritePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

        FavoriteCities();
    }
    private void FavoriteCities()
    {
        string cityName = Preferences.Get("cityName", "default_value");
        FavoriteCity.Text = cityName.ToString();
    }
}
```

Besides, if you want to pass the data to an already created page, you can use [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm) and store the city name in the data model.

Comment: Your method works, but when I try to update the content in the search engine and press the button again, the content does not update on the page Favorites.xaml

Comment: Can you check I update my question with your answer.

Comment: @BenJohnson I'm not sure what problem you encountered. Have posted my demo gif, and everything works fine. If possible, could you post a related gif? And what is "the content of the search bar is not updated"?

Comment: Can you show me your logic code from "GOTO" button ?

Comment: Can you check my Favorites.xaml.cs I update my question..

Comment: @BenJohnson The code in "Goto" is `Navigation.PushAsync(new FavoritePage());`. I have updated it in my `OnGetFavorites`. And the code you provided works fine in my test.